# TouchListener для ListView

Tags: android, listview

Есть приложение в котором необходимо перелистывать рабочую область(влево-вправо).

Рабочая область состоит из ListView, которому я присваиваю `setOnTouchListener(this);` Но тогда у ListView перестает работать скролл,обработка точечных нажатий и.т.д.

Можно ли как-нибудь настроить метод  `boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)`, чтобы он включался в работу,только когда пользователь делает длинные (листающие) движения. А в остальных случаях ListView работал бы как статичный.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            fromPosition = event.getX(); // берем точку нажатия
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: //вычисляем
            float toPosition = event.getX();
            if (fromPosition > toPosition ) {
                calendarView.addDay();

            } else if (fromPosition < toPosition) {
                calendarView.subDay();
            }
        default:
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: может лучше использовать ViewPager?

Comment: ViewPager уже рассматривал, там слишком сложно подстроить под мою задачу.

Comment: Естественно, костыль сделать проще под любую задачу. Но в вашем случае правильно будет использовать именно  `ViewPager`

Comment: ViewPager Не подойдет!!!!!

Comment: @Алексей попробуйте возвращать ```false``` если вы не обработали ```event``` который пришел в ```onTouch```.Т.е. в ```default``` и в условии если ```fromPosition``` == ```toPosition```

Comment: Опишите задачу вашу. И расскажите, почему для её решения не подойдёт `ViewPager` - возможно мы сможет вам помочь к нему прикрутить нужное поведение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделать такое можно. Гуглите OnSwipeTouchListener.